# Removing columns from a data.table using dplyr

Tags: regex, r, data.table, dplyr

I'm trying to remove columns in a `data.table` using the `select` function in the `dplyr` package, and am running into an error when no columns match my search pattern.

Using the standard `iris` data set and importing the appropriate packages,

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
select(data.table(iris), -matches("^Petal"))
# returns a table with three columns: Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Species
select(data.table(iris), -matches("^ER[[:digit:]]+$"))
# displays error message:
# Error in data.table::setnames(out, names(vars)) : x has no column names
```

Is there any way I can remove any columns matching the given regular expression (if they exist), and leave the table unmodified otherwise?

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
 iris[, !grepl("^ER[[:digit:]]+$", names(iris))]
```